# Parse.com caching with localDataStore enabled

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have caching problems in the iOS-Parse-SDK and I don't know what is wrong. I'm using the local datastore and it runs smoothly. But sometimes when I call a PFCloud function I don't get the current but an old version of an object or at least some fields of it are old (in my case it is a custom object with the field "status"). The strange thing is if I call the same function in the dev console on the Parse site I get the updated object. Is there anything I can do to prevent caching within the app or at least make sure I get the current version of an object?

Example PFCloud call:

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"importFriends"
                   withParameters:@{@"phoneNumbers": numbers}

                            block:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
                                if (!error) {
                                    DDLogDebug(@"Request Send Numbers SUCCESS: %@", result); //result objects are out of date
                                    if (successBlock) successBlock(result);
                                }else{
                                    DDLogDebug(@"Request Send Numbers FAIL: %@", error);
                                    if (failedBlock) failedBlock(error);
                                }
                            }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem like when you use the localdatastore and custom classes for any object you can't overwrite it's setters otherwise parse will never change it again. Even though the setter did exactly what a normal setter would do just a little bit more math afterwards.